# Confused about borrowing error in struct method

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write some code for an entity system in  a game but I'm getting this error so I've boiled the code into something that does the same thing, I get the same error in the actual code.

I don't understand why the compiler is telling me that the reference to `self.my_list` goes out of scope when the function `baz` finishes.

My rust version is `rustc 1.3.0 (9a92aaf19 2015-09-15)`

I would have thought that it goes out of scope when the `for` loop ends?

```
struct Foo {
    name : &'static str,
}

struct Bar {
    my_list : Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn New() -> Bar {
        let mut new_instance = Bar { my_list : vec!() };
        new_instance.my_list.push(Foo { name : "foo1" });
        new_instance.my_list.push(Foo { name : "foo2" });
        new_instance.my_list.push(Foo { name : "foo3" });
        return new_instance;
    }

    fn Baz(&mut self, name : &'static str) -> Option<&Foo> {
        for x in &self.my_list {
            if x.name == name {
                return Some(x);
            }
        }

        self.my_list.push(Foo { name : "foo" });

        return None;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar::New();
    if let Some(x) = bar.Baz("foo1") {
        println!("{} found", x.name);
    }
}
```

This is the error message that I get:

```
Compiling tutorial v0.1.0 (file:///C:/Code/Projects/rust/tutorial)
src\main.rs:35:9: 35:21 error: cannot borrow `self.my_list` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
src\main.rs:35         self.my_list.push(Foo { name : "foo" });
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src\main.rs:29:19: 29:31 note: previous borrow of `self.my_list` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `self.my_list` until the borrow ends
src\main.rs:29         for x in &self.my_list {
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src\main.rs:29:9: 33:10 note: expansion site
src\main.rs:38:6: 38:6 note: previous borrow ends here
src\main.rs:28     fn Baz(&mut self, name : &'static str) -> Option<&Foo> {
...
src\main.rs:38     }
                   ^
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `tutorial`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Comment: that's odd... even if you put the for loop into its own scope the same error occurs...

Comment: This only occurs if you return references in the for-loop. MCVE of your issue is here: http://is.gd/dJFkUz

Comment: The [desugared version](http://is.gd/atsegO) experiences the same problem. This certainly is feeling like a bug...

Comment: kindof a bug, more of an oversight I think... It's most likely going to be fixed by SEME

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the borrow checker.  The way you're reasoning that the function is safe is essentially treating the function as two paths: along the path where the function returns `Some(x)`, you don't borrow `my_list` again, and along the path where the function returns `None`, the borrow ends after the for loop.

That isn't the way the borrow checker looks at the function; the borrow checker works in terms of lexical scopes.  It tries to pick a scope as narrow as possible, but it will treat the the whole function as the scope if necessary.  It sees that the lifetime in the return value is the same as the lifetime of `self`, therefore the lifetime of the value referenced by `x` must be the same as `self`, therefore the borrow `&self.my_list` must have the same lifetime as `self`, therefore the borrow lasts beyond the return of the function.

If you write the function differently, Rust will accept it:

```
fn Baz(&mut self, name : &'static str) -> Option<&Foo> {
    match self.my_list.iter().position(|x| x.name == name) {
        Some(i) => Some(&self.my_list[i]),
        None => {
            self.my_list.push(Foo { name : "foo" });
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *the borrow checker works in terms of lexical scopes* — except in this case, a separate lexical scope does not help. The [desugared version](http://is.gd/atsegO) or the [sugared version](http://is.gd/EHmRrU) both have lexical scopes that don't help.

Comment: I tried to clarify.  The scope of the variables don't matter; the issue is the scope of the borrow, which can be expanded beyond the immediate lexical scope.